# Append RSpec shared examples with example groups to other randomly ordered examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have some shared examples with a bunch of context and/or it blocks, which I need to execute after all the other example groups in that file have been executed.
(The reason for this order dependency is that I'm testing a lot of different filter options and this particular test iterates over all the predefined filter settings that have not been tested specifically and is supposed to test their basic functionalities / in common results.)

I do want to keep the random order of all the other examples (`RSpec.configure { |config| config.order = :random }`).

`after(:context)` doesn't work for me because I can't `include_examples` from there.

```
RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::WrongScopeError: `include_examples` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block).
```

I've been looking into overriding order and one doable option seems to be:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.register_ordering(:append_to_random) do |items|
    items.randomize
    items << tests_to_append
  end
end
```

(`.randomize` is just supposed to be a synonym for some randomizing logic here)

And then somehow identify that `tests_to_append` (maybe using a tag?).
But that seems like a very *hacky* way, to achieve something, that's pretty simple in theory.
So my actual question is, if there is better / good / sexy way to achieve this?

Comment: What you said (a custom ordering that looks at tags) is the best I can think of, and it doesn't seem all that hacky given the requirements. But I would fight hard to remove the need to run the tests in a given order.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the reply! I suppose I'll give it some more thought.

Comment: I'm starting to realize that I got another problem, independent of which course of action I want to take. What I'm trying to do, requires looping over a bunch of hashes that represent my filter options (defined by a `before(:context)` block) and for every filter I want to execute some shared examples. I'm not even sure if that's possible? I need to be inside an example block to access my filters, but can't be inside an example to run my shared examples

Comment: Probably possible, and probably better as its own question than a comment.